# Why is the complexity of reverse algorithm O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have this implementation of `reverse` algorithm:

```
function reverse(a) {
    let left = 0;
    let right = a.length - 1;

    while (left < right) {
        let tmp = a[left];
        a[left] = a[right];
        a[right] = tmp;

        left += 1;
        right -= 1;
    }

    return a;
}
```

For any array of `n` elements the loop will run `n/2` times. But I read everywhere that `reverse` algorithm complexity is `O(n)`? So why is the complexity `O(n)`? Because of two operations on each cycle?

Comment: Looks like a question for https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Big-O notation ignores the constant in front of each term.

Comment: Big O notation is not affected by constant multipliers - so whether you have `n/2` operations `1000*n` operations, both will simply be `O(n)`

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: It I really important for you? Just use exists Array.prototype.reverse and show your users cats in internet.

Answer (score 0):

The Big-O of an algorithm refers to the time complexity of the algorithm in terms of n. Since the reverse method increases linearly with n, it is said to be O(n) even though the number of swaps may c*n (with c constant)

Answer (score -1):

o(n) means a function of n or some multipler of n ( not any other power of n) . n/2 a function of n (not n power -1 or n power2) hence its o(n). 
p.s.-this is based on the question of o(n) without even going to the logic of the code

Comment: There is no shift button on your keyboard? It is called Big-O for a reason.... Also this definition of *O(n)* is not correct. `e^x` is also *"a function of n"*, but is not *O(n)*.

Comment: I thought that was something else. Something after manipulating G

Comment: I get what you're trying to say with "a function of n", but e.g. n^2 is a function of n, so that's just confusing / misleading.